# Get result parameter of stored procedure in exec clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that returns multiple parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestSP]
    @Test1 INT
    , @Test2 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

    --some inserts and alters here

    SELECT TOP 1
          @Parameter1 AS Design
        , @Parameter2
        , @Parameter3
    FROM Table
```

I want to use `EXEC` into another stored procedure and get ONLY `@Parameter1 (Design)`

So I want to get `@Parameter1` after EXEC stored procedure, so I think about OUTPUT, but it doesn't work, is there a way to achieve this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SecondStoredProcedure]
    @Sender1 INT
    , @Sender2 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

    DECLARE @ReturnedParameter1 INT

    EXEC [dbo].[TestSP] @Test1 = @Sender1, @Test2 = @Sender2 OUTPUT [Design] 
    INTO @ReturnedParameter1 

    SELECT @ReturnedParameter1
```

Comment: Its really not clear what you are asking... Please show the full definition on each SP, and clarify what you mean by return, because you are selecting in your example, not returning.

Comment: Also please read the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) because they will most likely answer your questions.

Comment: And where are `@Parameter1`, `@Parameter2` & `@Parameter3` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That procedure creates a resultset, and has no output parameters.  You can capture a resultset with `insert into ... exec`, like this:

```
use tempdb
go

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[addDesign]
             @Test1                      INT
            ,@Test2                       UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
as
begin
--some inserts and alters here

    SELECT 
          1 AS Design
        , 2 as Foo
        , 3 as Bar

end
go

declare @rv table(Design int, Foo int, Bar int)

declare @test2 uniqueidentifier = newid()

insert into @rv
exec addDesign 1, @test2

declare @design int = (select Design from @rv)

select @design
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using an `output` parameter as explained in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Here is how your code might look in this case:

```
use tempdb
go

create procedure [dbo].[addDesign]
(
  @Test1 int
  , @Test2 uniqueidentifier
  , @Design int out
)
as
begin
  set nocount on;

  --some inserts and alters here

  -- Set the return parameter
  set @Design = @Parameter1;

  -- Select the return results
  SELECT TOP 1
    @Parameter1
    , @Parameter2
    , @Parameter3
  FROM dbo.MyTable;

  -- Return status code, proc ran OK
  return 0;
end
go

create procedure [dbo].[SecondStoredProcedure]
(
  @Sender1 int
  , @Sender2 uniqueidentifier
)
as
begin
  set nocount on;

  declare @ReturnedParameter1 int;

  exec dbo.TestSP @Test1 = @Sender1, @Test2 = @Sender2, @Design = @ReturnedParameter1; 

  select @ReturnedParameter1;

  -- Return status code, proc ran OK
  return 0;
end
go
```

Note: This demonstrates the 3 ways information can be returned from a stored procedure, the result code (only 1), output parameters (0-N) and result sets (0-N).